# How to test POST action on view with form in Flask

Tags: python, forms, testing, flask

I have a flask application that has a view function that looks like this:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/suspect_tracker/new_list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_list():
    form = ListForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.private:
            privacy_setting = 1
        else:
            privacy_setting = 0
        new_list = List(name=form.name.data, last_updated=datetime.utcnow(), user_id=g.user.id, private=privacy_setting)
        db.session.add(new_list)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New list %s added' % new_list.name)
        return redirect('/suspect_tracker/' + form.name.data)
    else:
        flash(form.name.errors)

    return render_template('newlist.html', title="Make a new list!", form=form)
```

And I am attempting to write a test for it, with the test looking like this:

```
from config import basedir
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, List, Suspect, SuspectList
from flask import g
from flask_testing import TestCase

class TestViews(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
        self.client = app.test_client()

        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = self.create_app()
        db.create_all()

        test_user = User(nickname="test")

        db.session.add(test_user)
        db.session.commit()

        g.user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_new_list_view(self):
        self.client.get('/suspect_tracker/new_list/')

        form = {'name':'Test', 'private':False}

        g.user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

        self.client.post('/suspect_tracker/new_list', data=form)

        assert List.query.filter_by(name="Test").first() != None
```

<strike>After running the test, the assertion fails, and I have tested to see that after running `self.client.post`, `List` does not contain a new list, and is still empty. This leads me to believe that `form.validate_on_submit()` returned `false`, which leads me to believe that I am not passing the correct data in the `self.client.post()` function in `test_new_list_view()`. My question is, how do I correctly create a `ListForm()` in the testing function and then POST it with `self.client.post()` to test the `new_list()` function?</strike>

I've fixed the issue with getting the form data to properly be sent, so now the form validates but I have no idea how to set g.user to be the mock user so when I try running the test I get an "AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id'" error.

Comment: Where does `db` come from?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just copied the TestViews Class and not the whole tests.py file. I've added the imports that are in tests.py but db is imported from app at the start of the testing file.